# Hibernate Space in Database column Names Issue

Tags: hibernate

I have database which is already created.Column Name for databases contains spaces,special characters such as :- Person Name, "Person Address"  etc.

How to mention these things in hibernate-Mapping xml file? would it work in such conditions ?

??
Thanks,
Magician

Answer (score 0):

You can use [quoted identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)

```
<property name="personName" column="`Person Name`"/>
```